# How can I know when a tab was switched?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, appdelegate

I have an app where the UI is setup programmatically instead of using Storyboards.  I am stuck on how to know when a tab has been switched... and when it has been switched I want to be able to assign a property called "userSettings" in each view controller so that I can pass this object around and call methods on it appropriately.

Here is my app delegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var contentVC: BMContentViewController?
    var settingsVC: BMSettingsViewController?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        contentVC = BMContentViewController()
        contentVC?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        contentVC?.tabBarItem.title = "Content"

        settingsVC = BMSettingsViewController()
        settingsVC?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        settingsVC?.tabBarItem.title = "Settings"

        let tabbarController = UITabBarController()
        tabbarController.viewControllers = [(contentVC ?? UIViewController()), settingsVC ?? UIViewController()]

        self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {}
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}
}
```

BMContentViewController() and BMSettingsViewController() each have a property called:

```
var userSettings: BMUserSettings?
```

I start the app off in BMContentViewController().  When I switch tabs, I want to be able to assign the userSettings in BMSettingsViewController() to the userSettings that is in BMContentViewController().  userSettings is a central object in my app and instead of creating a singleton, I'm trying to get the app to work by just passing a reference to the object around to other view controllers.

I'm not sure if this is possible by detecting when the tab was switched and passing the value or if I need to use the delegate pattern instead?

How can I accomplish this? I'm trying to avoid using singletons.

Comment: You can assign a delegate to the tab bar controller to get a delegate callback [when the selected tab changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller), however if `BMUserSettings` is a class then you can just assign a single instance of this class to both view controllers when they are created.

Comment: This is what I did. Then I accessed the object thru the app delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data between view controllers in 6 ways:

1. `Instance` property (A → B)
2. `Segues` (for Storyboards)
3. `Instance` properties and functions (A ← B)
4. `Delegation` pattern - **you can try delegate pattern, this will be my first best option**
5. `Closure` or `completion handler`
6. `NotificationCenter` and the `Observer` pattern - **this will be the second best option in your case.**

Comment: One answer is missing. I can just access the app delegate and then the object from within it